# Why is the thread keep runing after I set the running flag to false?

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a thread running when flag is true,but when I change the flag to false, it does not go to die.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            MyThread mt = new MyThread();
            mt.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt.setRunning(false);
            System.out.println("set running false");
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class MyThread extends Thread
    {
        private boolean isRunning = true;

        public boolean isRunning()
        {
            return isRunning;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean isRunning)
        {
            this.isRunning = isRunning;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("run");
            while (isRunning == true){
            }
            System.out.println("run over!");
        }
    }
```

I know defining "isRunning" as volatile will solve the problem,but when not volatile, "isRunning" shouldn't be visible at some point to MyThread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to visibility reasons.

Make your variable volatile:

```
volatile private boolean isRunning = true;
```

See [What is the volatile keyword useful for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for) for more details.

> I know defining "isRunning" as volatile will solve the problem,but
>   when not volatile, "isRunning" shouldn't be visible at some point to
>   MyThread?

It's the value change of `isRunning` that you need to make visible to `MyThread` when the `main` thread changes it. Otherwise it might just continue seeing the cached value of `true`.

Comment: I know that using volatile will make the variable visible at once, but my question is without using volatile, I think the variable change will be visible to the thread in the future at some point,but the result seems the change of the variable will never be visible...

Comment: @ccc there is no such guarantee. The updated value might **never** be visible to another thread. This is mentioned in Java Concurrency in Practice book.

Answer (score 0):

There are two threads here. Every thread has a cache. When you don't add `volatile`, the thread reads the value from the owner cache. So, `myThread.isRunning` is true. By using `volatile`, the owner thread can forcibly write to memory and refresh the cache.